# Can anyone identify what appears to be a crashed WWII German plane?

Tags: military, aviation-history, fighter, wwii, germany

This photograph is in my family's photo collection.  The only information with the photo is, "Cousin Bud Kohl - aircraft wreck."   If anyone can identify the make and model it is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Although we can't see any markings, it is also possible the P-47 was one of those captured and flown by the Luftwaffe, or cannibalized to make the other captured aircraft flyable again, hence why it would be with parts of German airplanes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's a [P-47 Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_P-47_Thunderbolt), the original "razorback" version (not the later ones with the bubble canopy and cut-down rear fuselage).  The instant giveaway is the V shaped windshield, which had the armour glass as a separate panel behind it (removed in the pic). The bubble canopy versions have the armour glass as the windshield itself, like most other fighters.

The German rudder/fin looks to be a piece of a the right tail boom of a [Focke-Wulf FW 189](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Fw_189_Uhu).

My guess is that Bud is probably at a forward P-47 base that was an ex-Luftwaffe base (the brick wall behind suggests a large base with permanent buildings, possibly within Germany or Eastern France, in early 1945) and therefore still strewn with German wrecks.  The Jug in the picture has had what looks to have been a gear up landing and was dragged away to a bone yard area, and is being cannibalized for parts as required.

Comment: This is incredible information for me, and so detailed.  Thank you very much.  I never would have guessed a P-47 due to the German tail and wing in the pile. And the suggestion of a belly landing looks spot on due to the propeller damage.  This information is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  The brick wall there is quite distinctive, so if you search around on the web for "P-47 bases in Europe" or go to different P-47 squadron historical website pages, you might stumble on to a photo with that same building that nails down the precise location.  A little time rooting around may present a Eureka! moment.

Comment: I've heard that some P-47's were captured and flown by the Luftwaffe.

Comment: Yes there were and if you hunt around you'll find at least one pic of a Jug in a hangar with German markings. But I would say the scenario I described is more likely in the circumstances.

Answer (score 16):

This looks like a P-47 (twin row radial, 4-blade prop, unique canopy frame structure) that is part of a scrap pile with some German types in the mix.

Comment: Thank you, Niels.  You confirm the comment above.  I never would have guessed it to be a P-47.  Much appreciated.